# .Net 6 Dependency Injection AddDbContext , modificar conexion en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

queria saber si alguien sabe como modificar la conexion de un contexto en entity framework, cuando inicio el programa obtengo la cadena de conexion de "appsettings.json" y eso va perfecto, pero por otro lado, necesito que a traves de parametros que se me envia en un controlador, la cadena de conexion de ese DbContext que habia agregado en el ServiceProvider cambie.

Ejemplo de mi codigo:

En este caso, agrego la conexion cuando recien inicio el programa, tomando la cadena de conexion de "appsettings.json":

```
String connectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseMySql(
        connectionString,
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)
    )
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
});
```

Pero luego, en el siguiente controlador necesito que se modifique el db context de ese Service Provider

```
public class ProductController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetCustomers")]
    /*ESTO ES PARA UNICAMENTE LOS USUARIOS AUTORIZADOS [Authorize]*/
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IReadOnlyList<Product>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<Product>>> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        string CadenaDeConexion = "Micadenadeconexion";

        //ESTA ES MI BASE DE DATOS Y QUIERO CAMBIAR LA CONEXION DE ESTE CONTEXTO EN TIEMPO DE EJECUCION
        var db = ServiceLocator.GetService<StoreCustomersContext>();
        
        var result = (await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductSearcher>().GetAllAsync()).ToList();
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Saben si hay alguna manera de que en la clase esa del controlador o si hay alguna otra forma, de que en tiempo de ejecucion pueda modificar la cadena de conexion y que cargue nuevamente la nueva configuracion con la nueva cadena de conexion de mi DB CONTEXT("StoreCustomersContex") en mi "ServiceLocator" para que pueda seguir trabajando correctamente?

Mi clase service locator es del siguiente tipo:

```
public static class ServiceLocator
{
    private static IServiceProvider? provider;
    public static IServiceProvider Provider
    {
        set => provider = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(provider));
        get
        {
            if (provider == null) throw new Exception("Provider no inicializado");
            return provider;
        }
    }

    public static T GetService<T>() where T : notnull
    {
        return Provider.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    }
}
```

En esta clase se cargan todos los servicios de Dependency Injection

Answer (score 0):

Cambiar la cadena de conexion del contexto es bastante simple, en principio cada llamada al controlador crea un contexto nuevo, por lo que le cambio de cadena de conexin no se propagaria, no obstante yo soy un poco paranoico y suelo guardarme la cadena de conexion y dejarla como estaba en un finally  :

```
string saveConnString = _db.Database.GetConnectionString();
db.Database.SetConnectionString("la cadena de conexion especifica que quieres usar");
var result = (await ServiceLocator.GetService<ProductSearcher>().GetAllAsync()).ToList();
//Volvemos a dejar la cadena de conexion como estaba
db.Database.SetConnectionString(saveConnString);
return Ok(result);
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta , lo pude solucionar de otra forma, ahora comparto como logre hacerlo, de todas formas voy a intentar ver tambien la forma en la que es mas eficaz, a lo mejor la forma en la que mencionas es mejor que la que hice yo, ahi envio mi solucion!

Nuevamente, gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver enviando un parametro header requerido si o si , y capturandolo en mi startup.cs a la hora de agregar el db context

```
services.TryAddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddDbContext<StoreCustomersContext>(opt =>
{
    var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    string originUri = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers["originUri"];
    string connectionString = string.Empty;
    if (originUri == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(originUri))
    {
        connectionString = configurations.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    }
    else
    {
        if (originUri.Equals("1"))
        {
            connectionString = "test";
        }
        else
        {
            connectionString = "test2";
        }
    }

    opt.UseMySql(
        connectionString,
        ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)
    )
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
});
```